# php calculate total hours and minutes and seconds

Tags: php, time

I have an estimated total of several hours, Which consists of several hours - several minutes - several seconds.
something like this:170: 156: 230 which means 170 hours and 156 minutes and 230 seconds. now how can i turn this value into something like this:172: 59: 59.
total seconds should never exceed 59 seconds.
If more, the amount of overflow will increase to a minute. i would do the same for the sum of the minutes:
that is, the sum of minutes never exceeds 59, if it was,The amount of overflow will be added to the total number of hours.
I've already done this (which is not perfect, of course)

```
$raw_times = ['h'=>102, 'm'=>353, 's'=>345];

foreach (array_reverse($raw_times) as $type => $value) {
     switch ($type) {
         case 's':
             if (60 < $value) {
                 while ((60 < $value) && (0 <= $value)) {
                     $sec_overlap += 60;
                     $value -= 60;
                 }

                $raw_times['s'] = $value;
                $raw_times['m'] += $sec_overlap;
                return $raw_times;
            }
                break;
                case 'm':
                    // some thing like above...
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple calculation by dividing 60.

```
function convert($param) {
    $hms = array_map('intval', explode(':', $param));
    $hms[1] += floor($hms[2] / 60);
    $hms[2] %= 60;

    $hms[0] += floor($hms[1] / 60);
    $hms[1] %= 60;

    return implode(': ', $hms);
}

echo convert('170: 156: 230 ');
```

If you use parameter as array:

```
function convert($hms) {
    $hms['m'] += floor($hms['s'] / 60);
    $hms['s'] %= 60;

    $hms['h'] += floor($hms['m'] / 60);
    $hms['m'] %= 60;

    return $hms;
}

print '<pre>';
print_r(convert(['h'=>102, 'm'=>353, 's'=>345]));
print '</pre>';
```